# Change Mac username

Tags: snow-leopard, imac

How can I change the username that pops up every time admin access is requested ?

I've tried updating the account name in System Preferences -> Accounts

Comment: Apologies, im using snow-leopard. In spotlight I can find system preferences and from there "Accounts". Yes I mean the full name

Comment: What happens when you change the name in System Preferences? Is the account to which you refer an administrator account? (i.e. is the "Allow user to administer this computer" box checked?)

Comment: Name stays the same when I change it (does not change). Yes the user is an administrator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try clicking the lock button to authenticate before you make the changes (you probably have to do this anyway), make the changes and then click the lock again. Then click Show All to properly exit from the Accounts preference pane.

If this does not resolve the issue, you may want to do a permissions repair from Disk Utility on your startup volume. If that does not resolve the issue, try restarting your computer from the recovery partition (if running Lion) or the gray disk (if not running Lion). Open Disk Utility and run a permissions repair on your startup volume. After this is complete, close Disk Utility and open Terminal from the Utilities menu. Type in resetpassword and select your user account (NOT System Administrator/root) from the drop down menu. Click the Reset button at the bottom of the window in the Reset home folder permissions and ACLs section. Quit the Password Utility and go back to the main recovery screen. On your keyboard, hit Command+Q and restart your computer.

It's very important that you don't hold down the power button to exit the recovery session, or the ACL reset won't occur.

Answer (score 3):

To change the Full Name of a user, you make the change at the **Users and Groups** panel of System Preferences. To change the username is technically a much more difficult thing to do, and cannot be done from the GUI.

[image]

Comment: I have "Accounts" instead of "Users and Groups"

Comment: @user5332: same thing; the name of the preference pane was "Accounts" in Snow Leopard, but changed to "Users and Groups" in Lion.